# LLVM Use Of Instruction Is Not An Instruction

Tags: c, clang, ocaml, llvm, llvm-ir

I've seen one post on here about the "use of instruction is not an instruction" error, and I'm running into a similar issue, but without a good reason.

I'm using moe (https://llvm.moe/ocaml/Llvm.html) to write LLVM to build a compiler and my issue basically comes down to 3 lines:

```ml
let pointer = L.build_alloca float_t ("reg") builder in      L.dump_value(pointer);
  let test = L.build_store (L.const_float float_t 32.3) pointer builder      in L.dump_value(test);
   let loaded = L.build_load pointer ("reg") builder  in L.     dump_value(loaded);
```

what I'm doing here is basically using alloc to get some space in memory, then storing the value of 32.3 to that space, and trying to *load it back into the place I allocated in memory*.

LLVM wise, it looks pretty good, as, after the dump_module, output, I get something like this:

```
align 8  %reg = alloca double, align 8 
store double 3.230000e+01, double* %reg, align 8
%x13 = load double, double* %reg, align 8
```

which should be exactly what I want -- I even tested this out by writing up a similar C program and it does something very similar to this in LLVM.

However, when I run my program I get the following error:

```
Use of instruction is not an instruction!
 %x13 = load double, double* %reg, align 8
```

which really doesn't seem to make sense. I check out the error a bit more, and it seems like it's caused by a few lines in the LLVM source code:

```
     if (Instruction *Used = dyn_cast<Instruction>(U.getUser()))
       Assert(Used->getParent() != nullptr,
              "Instruction referencing"
              " instruction not embedded in a basic block!",
              &I, Used);
     else {
       CheckFailed("Use of instruction is not an instruction!", U);
       return;
     }
   }
```

which seem to imply it happens if the instructions don't have a parent, but I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Any help here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What is `%x12`? Can you dump it?

Comment: ah yeah sorry about that, forgot to paste in, should be "%reg", not %x12 -- edited post

Comment: To debug this, break into debugger, get to the failing assertion and run `U.getUser()->dump()`. The problem is not with `%reg` operand, but with a user of `%x13`.

Comment: What @arrowd says here is precisely what I too would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LLVM has constants and instructions. Constants are things such as 12, but also functions and global variables (which have constant addresses). Instructions are things that involve some sort of action.

Constants can use constants (for example, a constant's initialiser can reference other constants). Instructions can use constants (for example, you can store to a global variable). Instructions can use instructions (for example, you can load from an address which is the result of an instruction).

But constants cannot use instructions.

When the code that asserts looks at `%x13 = load double, double* %reg`, the `User` variable points to the the operand (`%reg`) and the operand's parent is the load instruction. I don't know what it points to when it asserts, but whatever `->getParent()` returns isn't an instruction, and whatever is being used is one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response; I'm not quite sure what you mean -- you're saying that when I call `%x13 = load double, double* %reg` the parent instruction is load. Is this the same load instruction we just called? Or something separate? Like is there any more code I could show that would identify the problem?

Comment: I'm telling you that the parent mentioned in the LLVM code isn't the instruction's parent (as you seem to believe), but rather it is an operand's parent. It asserts because an operand belonging to a non-instruction uses an instruction.

Comment: Ah okay I see -- so is there a way to essentially create an operand that belongs to an instruction and do what I'm trying to accomplish here by allocating space in memory, placing a constant in that space, and then loading that constant in memory into another register?

Comment: That should be possible. It sounds as if the mistake is elsewhere... I suspect it's not actually complaing about those three lines. Try checking precisely what User->getParent() is. Most LLVM objects let you call ->dump() in the debugger.

Comment: Update on this! I was able to fix it, as you said, the getParent() assertion was failing and this was because of how I was actually handling %x13. So, for anyone else with a similar issue just make sure you're correctly using whatever you return in %x13 -- good explanation here too: https://llvm.discourse.group/t/use-of-instruction-is-not-an-instruction/3355/3